# Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters

Tags: java, jce

The code belows is throwing this error message:

`Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters`

```
Cipher dcipher;

byte[] salt = new String("12345678").getBytes();
int iterationCount = 1024;
int keyStrength = 256;
SecretKey key;
byte[] iv;

Decrypter(String passPhrase) throws Exception {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
            .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    System.out.println("factory +" + factory);
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt,
            iterationCount, keyStrength);
    System.out.println("spec  " + spec);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    System.out.println();
    key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
}

public String encrypt(String data) throws Exception {
    dcipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    AlgorithmParameters params = dcipher.getParameters();
    iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    byte[] utf8EncryptedData = dcipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    String base64EncryptedData = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()
            .encodeBuffer(utf8EncryptedData);

    System.out.println("IV "
            + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(iv));
    System.out.println("Encrypted Data " + base64EncryptedData);
    return base64EncryptedData;
```

Does anybody know why I get that error?

Comment: In which line is the exception being thrown? please mark

Comment: Do you have the `Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy File` installed? 256-bit AES (From the Java crypto package) cannot be used unless that file is installed onto your computer.

Comment: For this problem I had to download `Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8`

Answer (score 24):

Probably you did not install the JCE Policy file yet.

Download this file:

- [Java 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html)
- [Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)
- [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)

And Install the file in `${java.home}/jre/lib/security/.`

`${java.home}` refers to your installation directory of Java

for mac:

- open finder
- press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>
- type `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`
- navigate to your version of JDK
- then `Contents/Home/jre/lib/security`
- unzip the downloaded file and place all files inside here

for CLI

```
unzip downloaded_policy_file.zip  -d /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<JDK_VERSION>/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/

mv /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<JDK_VERSION>/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK<VERSION>/* /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<JDK_VERSION>/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security  

rm -rf Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<JDK_VERSION>/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK<VERSION>/
```

Comment: but what is the reason why we have to explicitly paste the downloaded Jars as it already contains the same....

Comment: how to add them if we using Netbeans ???

Answer (score 1):

Download the JCE for Java 7 from this link 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

and open the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\security` and paste the two jars here.(Even if the two jars were already present replace those two jars)

Answer (score 0):

For JAVA 7 the download link is [jce-7-download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)

Copy the two downloaded jars in Java\jdk1.7.0_10\jre\lib\security
Take a backup of older jars to be on safer side.

Comment: but what is the reason why we have to download and paste Jars explicitly even it already has the same....

Comment: the content of the jars is different. For example the original jars are limiting the possible key length, so the encryption is rather weak. I think it is based on US export policy.

Answer (score 0):

In case you using Mac with homebrew

```
brew cask install jce-unlimited-strength-policy
```

Answer (score 0):

As of JDK 1.8u151 it is not necessary to download the JCE libraries separately.  Simply edit:

```
$JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security
```

and uncomment the line:

```
crypto.policy=unlimited
```