# Java - AES 256 works in JDK 7 and JDK 9 but not in JDK 8

Tags: java, encryption

I wrote this class using the new JDK 9 release.

```
public class Encrypters {
    public static byte[] AESEncrypt(Key key, byte[] data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] encryptedData=cipher.doFinal(data);
        return encryptedData;
    }
}
```

I also wrote this helper class

```
public class Hashes {
    public static byte[] sha256Hash(byte[] input) {
        return hash(input, "SHA-256");
    }

    private static byte[] hash(byte[] input, String algorithm) {
        MessageDigest md=null;
        try {
            md=MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}
        return md.digest(input);
    }
}
```

This is the usage to encrypt a String:

```
String password=...;
String data=...;
Key key=new SecretKeySpec(Hashes.sha256Hash(password.getBytes(), "AES"));
Encrypters.AESEncrypt(key, data.getBytes());
```

This code runs with both JDK 9 and JDK 7, but not with JDK 8.
If I try to run with JDK 8 I get this error:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
```

Why do I get this error? Is AES-256 not supported by Java 8?

Comment: It may not be relevant, but you should always define all aspects of your cipher.  Don't just use "AES".  You should also not be using ECB mode.  Use "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" instead.

Answer (score 4):

It is supported, you just need to update your Java 8 JRE ([link](https://golb.hplar.ch/p/JCE-policy-changes-in-Java-SE-8u151-and-8u152)), or include the JCE policy file ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856324/exception-in-thread-main-java-security-invalidkeyexception-illegal-key-size-o))
The strong encryption was never included in the JRE by default, in the latest distributions it is. The reason why it works for Java 7 in your case, is probably because it is 7u171 or later. See 
[JDK-8170157](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170157) for details on when this was backported to different versions.